# Perform Azure Purview Scan thru API

Tags: azure, azure-purview

I have registered the source (ADLS2) thru Azure portal and have done the initial scan. I am aware that I can schedule the scan.
But I would like to know if I can perform source scan in Azure Purview thru an API.

I have gone thru the below link but no luck.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/tutorial-using-rest-apis

Any helps from MSFT team? Thanks.

Comment: Please use these tools to call the Azure Purview APIs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69081978/what-are-the-various-tools-and-utilities-to-invoke-azure-purview-apis-scripts

Comment: Please use these tools to call the Azure Purview APIs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69081978/what-are-the-various-tools-and-utilities-to-invoke-azure-purview-apis-scripts

Answer (score 1):

The official tutorial [Use the REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/tutorial-using-rest-apis), (currently) only covers the *Apache Atlas* endpoint.

Microsoft actually mentions in [Deployment best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/deployment-best-practices#create-a-process-to-move-to-production) that it is recommended to use the "REST API route" to manage "scan rule sets" (and several other tasks).

My guess is, that managing Purview high-level configurations, such as connections & scans, is done via another non-Atlas endpoint. But I have not been able to find any official documentation on this.

You can use the [Azure Purvice CLI](https://github.com/tayganr/purviewcli) (3rd party Python CLI) to complete your task. Specifically, the [scan](https://github.com/tayganr/purviewcli#scan) feature:

```
pv scan run --datasource=<val> --scanName=<val> [--scanLevel=<val>]
```

UPDATE: According to this [purviewcli illustration](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tayganr/purviewcli/master/doc/image/purview_components.png), there are 3 main endpoints "catalog", "scan", and "guardian".

UPDATE 2: Here is the documentation on the [Purview Scans REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/purview/scanningdataplane/scans)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of the various tools and utilities to make Purview Adoption smoother and lightning fast amongst Azure Purview community, developers, ISVs, partners, evangelists and Customers. This article contains various command line and powershell tools to invoke Azure Purview APIs; and all these utilities are invigorated with automation interfaces.

1. [Purview-API-via-Powershell](https://aka.ms/purview-api-ps) : This utility is derived from Microsoft Docs [Purview API Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/purview/) and helps you automate Purview deployment via APIs through a breezy fast and easy to use Powershell interface. Use and automate Purview APIs for regular and long term usage via command-line and scripted methods as against the UI way of using the portal. [Portal use is the greatest and most user friendly method for one time and non-recurring use, but for large enterprise deployment and recurring tasks or actions on your Purview account using automation, scripted way is the best technique.]
2. [Purview Lab](https://aka.ms/purviewlab) : A hands-on-lab introducing the myriad features of Purview and helping you learn the concepts in a practical and hands-on approach where you execute each step on your own by hand to develop the best possible understanding of Purview.
3. [Purview CLI](https://aka.ms/purviewcli) : Another technique of using the Purview APIs similar to [Purview-API-via-Powershell](https://aka.ms/purview-api-ps) , only difference being this tool is Python based, whereas the former is Powershell based.
4. [Purview Demo](https://aka.ms/pvdemo) : A lightning fast tool to automatically deploy Purview in a super fast and secure way at the click of a button. It just asks for your corporate email address - as simple as that ! Click a button, wait 10 minutes and boom - your Purview environment is up and running, ready to use via Azure portal, Purview Studio or any of the Purview APIs.